# Converting mobile website to jQuery mobile + Phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I currently have a mobile website that I am converting to use jQuery mobile and Phonegap. This is my first time using both Phonegap and jQuery mobile. I am using $.mobile.changePage('www.mysite.com/index.php'); to transition to new pages. Is it possible to call the Camera functions from index.php, or do I have to do it directly in the native Phonegap files?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, but apple won't approve your app. The right way is having the html, css and javascript locally, and getting JSON or XML data from the server using XHR calls

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile has many issues with PhoneGap, bad performance, bad page navigation, bad others.... Try another framework, though jqm is possible.